# Add values of a column of 2 list of objects where 1 column's value is the same in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This is my output in sql server

```
CODE  |  TYPE  |   COUNT
ABC       1         10
ABC       2         20
DEF       3         30
DEF       1         11
DEF       2         12
XYZ       3         13
XYZ       1         20
XYZ       3         21

======================

CODE  |  TYPE  |   COUNT
ABC       1         11
ABC       2         30
DEF       3         25
DEF       1         20
DEF       2         10
XYZ       3         11
XYZ       1         12
XYZ       3         15
```

I put this in 2 different lists of objects from the database

```
public class MyObject 
{
    public string Code;
    public string Type;
    public int Count
}

var resultSetA = await result.ReadAsync<MyObject>();
var resultSetB = await result.ReadAsync<MyObject>();
```

How can I add the 2 lists of objects that I can get a result like this

```
CODE  |  TYPE  |   SetA+SetB     
ABC       1          21     
ABC       2          50
DEF       3          55
DEF       1          31
DEF       2          22
XYZ       3          24
XYZ       1          22
XYZ       3          36
```

Comment: What is `ReadAsync`? `MyObject` == `PlazaReading`?

Comment: Sorry about that. Please see my edit.

Comment: Can you please expand `var`'s for `resultSet`'s? Also is duplication of `XYZ       3 ` intended or is it a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `resultSet`'s are lists/enumerables - you can use LINQ to concatenate and group values and perform aggregation into new ones:

```cs
var result = resultSetA.Concat(resultSetB)
    .GroupBy(o => (o.Code, o.Type))
    .Select(gr => new MyObject
    {
        Code = gr.Key.Code,
        Type = gr.Key.Type,
        Count = gr.Sum(o => o.Count)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Any pointers on where I can learn the way you do linqs? Anyways, this is correct. Thank you.

Comment: @Ibanez1408  there is some info in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/), though I find it not that easy to consume. There are also some [official videos online](https://youtu.be/p5myHVOtmiU). Also check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/try-samples/101-linq-samples/). Also "LINQ Pocket Reference" by Joseph Albahari can be useful.

Comment: I will definitely study that. Thank you for the knowledge share, Sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Join` from `System.Linq`:

```
var sum = resultSetA.Join(resultSetB, 
                a => new { a.Code, a.Type, },
                b => new { b.Code, b.Type, },
                (a, b) => new MyObject()
                {
                    Code = a.Code,
                    Type = a.Type,
                    Count = a.Count + b.Count,
                });
```

Remember this will return an `Enumerable`. If you need a `List`, you can simply cast it with `ToList()` method.

Comment: This will not work correctly if there are missing keys on one of the sides for example (not represented in the sample data)